# MapServer Integration with ZOO Project on Windows 10

Tags: wms, mapserver, wps, zoo-project

I installed ZOO Project using the package installer (x64-72). To add MapServer, I installed ms4w using the zip file (ran apache-install.bat) and added the zoo project application. I also added the mapserverAddress pointing to the mapserv.exe on Apache in main.cfg of ZOO Project (running on IIS).

When I execute HelloPy or any other service with "useMapserver = true" in the services configuration file, I get the following error

> ZOO Kernel failed to process your request, receiving signal 11 = SIGSEGV

Also, in the dataPath directory, two files, a .data file and a .zip file are added. If I pass in a shapefile's zip for HelloPy, the .data file shows some unreadable content while the .zip contains a .cst file, which in turn only shows some character encoding (ISO ... ).

Can someone please help me with this issue?

**EDIT:** I found that a part of my issue was that I was not passing in a file that could be understood by GDAL. On making this change I can see that the .map file is generated along with the two files mentioned above. However, the SIGSEVG error still exists.

**EDIT 2:**
If I pass a WMS result to MapServer (say image/jpeg, image/geotiff) a mapfile is generated along with the other 2 files but the SIGSEGV error persists. If I pass in image/geotiff8 instead, then the result is a link for a getmap request. However, this link does not show any result.

If WFS results are passed in instead, like a kml, then the result is a vector map instead of the desired raster. What should I do?

Comment: Possibly you have a port conflict.   if you use MS4W and ran  apache-install.bat then you have an Apache HTTP web server installed running on port 80, and all files Ms4w will be expecting to run on Apache.  But now you also have IIS, a competing web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked was configuring MapServer to work on IIS by following [the guidance on IIS Setup at MapServer.org](http://www.mapserver.org/installation/iis.html). Then passing in data which was of KML type worked - it returns a GetMap request using the new mapfile it generates (for WPS 1.0.0 only).

However, the zoo-error.txt still shows the error

> Unable to access the DataSource as ZIP File

Comment: If one thing worked but you still have an error, I'm not sure if this is an answer, instead of an edit to the question, or whether you have a second question.